# After making hyper link there is change in description

Tags: excel, vba

I want to make hyper link for cell in VBA, but when I run the code I do not get:
**H:/Pro/ ...** 
but it is making me line this one:
**\sigma**  
The H:/ drive is the network drive and maybe this is the problem but I do not know how to solve it.

```
Sub Test_link()
Dim ark8 As Worksheet
Set ark8 = Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim MyLink As String, MyLink2 As String
MyLink = "H:/Pro/"

MyLink2 = MyLink & ark8.Cells(1, "A")
ark8.Hyperlinks.Add Range("A1"), Address:=MyLink2
End Sub
```

I also check the text what is making during the process and it is OK
 ```  Msgbox MyLink2 ``` but during making the link this sentens is change, as I wrote erlier. 
When I change sentens in link '//sigma/' manualy it is working ok but I do not know how to stop excel making change in mine text when the link is make.

Comment: What is ark8.Cells(1, "A")'s value?

Comment: Name of the folder.